# Display NumberOfRowsInSection to a Label in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Is there anyway that i can display the number of rows in section from my tableview in one ViewController to a Label in another View controller.

As an Example:

My tableview on View 2 of the tab bar controller has a list of names.

i want to display the amount of that list of names as an Int in a label on view 1 of my tab bar controller

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: you can do it with many ways : for example make an instance of your table view from parrent view and ask about data source , another way : check the data source manually (Fetch from db or check your array from view 1)

Comment: @JeffC I am fairly new to swift, actually teaching myself from scratch. What i did was i checked my array on view 1 by doing var info: [ClientInfo], then i added my initializer from view 2 to view 1 and connected it to the label on view 1.  The problem was, It only showed the Number "3" which was the amount of items in my initializer. but when i went and added more to the tableview. the # stayed at 3.

Comment: @MohamadFarhand As i am new to swift any suggestions on what i can watch or learn from as to learn how to do that?